# How to use right click paste in the IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, click, paste

[image]I can use right click pace in the CMD, but it seems not an option to use it in the IntelliJ IDEA. It only has paste on middle mouse button click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not available yet. Feel free to go to [IDEA-118892](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118892) and vote for it to stay updated.

Answer (score 5):

It supports paste by middle click!